# Laravel 4: route in group throwing notfoundhttpexception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've noticed a bit of a peculiarity in Laravel 4 when using Routes. I have a Route group that looks like this:

```
// Employers routes
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'employers'), function(
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'employers.index', 'uses' => 'EmployersController@index'));
    Route::get('create', array('as' => 'employers.create', 'uses' => 'EmployersController@create'));
    Route::post('/', array('as' => 'employers.store', 'uses' => 'EmployersController@store', 'before' => 'csrf'));
    Route::get('search', array('as' => 'employers.search', 'uses' => 'EmployersController@search'));
    Route::get('{id}', array('as' => 'employers.show', 'uses' => 'EmployersController@show'));
    Route::get('{id}/edit', array('as' => 'employers.edit', 'uses' => 'EmployersController@edit'));
    Route::patch('{id}/update', array('as' => 'employers.update', 'uses' => 'EmployersController@update', 'before' => 'csrf'));
    Route::delete('{id}/destroy', array('as' => 'employers.destroy', 'uses' => 'EmployersController@destroy', 'before' => 'csrf'));
));
```

I've noticed, however, that when I try and add in a new route I have to add it before the first route to use the `{id}` wildcard as the first parameter in it's url, otherwise I get a `notfoundhttpexception`. Is this normal? So for example, this works (adding in the `employers.search` route:

```
// Employers routes
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'employers'), function(
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'employers.index', 'uses' => 'EmployersController@index'));
    Route::get('create', array('as' => 'employers.create', 'uses' => 'EmployersController@create'));
    Route::post('/', array('as' => 'employers.store', 'uses' => 'EmployersController@store', 'before' => 'csrf'));
    Route::get('{id}', array('as' => 'employers.show', 'uses' => 'EmployersController@show'));
    Route::get('search', array('as' => 'employers.search', 'uses' => 'EmployersController@search'));
}
```

Results in the route `employers.search` not being found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Routes are evaluated in a top-down fashion.

`{id}` is a "catch all" route.

So the route system sees `/search` - and thinks `search` is an `{id}` - so it loads that route. But then it cannot find an id of `search` - and so it fails.

So keep your "catch all" route at the bottom of the list - and it will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had guessed that this might be working as intended but wasn't too sure :)